What is the oldest way to measure the voltage?
What is the oldest way to measure the voltage?
I mean the experimental way or apparatus.

Frog Galvanoscope after the discovery that frog legs twitch when exposed to electricity by Luigi Galvani in 1781.

For a comprehensive account see Keithley, The Story of Electrical and Magnetic Measurements: From 500 BC to the 1940s.

I see you've edited the question. By "measure a voltage" do you mean to simply determine that a potential difference exists, or an actual quantitative measurement e.g. 2 volts vs 1.5 volts? I'm not sure the frog leg twitch scale was quantitative enough for you.
